# MetaData navigation with URL filtering

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering, metadata-navigation

So i was opening my document library from my custom web app with passing column filters in URL (query string). Now i need to use metadata navigation heirarchy but problem with this is that once you navigate from one node to another (in metadata navigation) my URL filters are lost since SharePoint creates a new URL on each click and overwrite my custom URL.

Now SharePoint does maintain column filters if you use key filters, I can not use key filters so is there a way i can construct a URL using some javascript that maintains both metadata navigation and my column filters at the same time if i navigate from node to another in metadata navigation?